# Inequalities with absolute values

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, absolute-value

My question is:

> Show that for all $|x-1|+|x-2|+\dots+|x-10| > 23$

I have solved above problem as below,

If $x-1 > 0$ and $x-2 > 0$ and ......$x-10 > 0$ then

LHS $= x-1+x-2+x-3+\dots+x-10 = 10x-55 > 23$ (because $x>10$)

If $x-1<0$ and $x-2 < 0$ and ......$x-10 < 0$ then

LHS $= -x+1-x+2-x+3.....-x+10 = -10x+55 > 23 $ (because $x<1$)

If the above solution is wrong, please give me the correct method

Comment: You can optimise your check. E.g, if  $x-1 < 0$, then certainly $x-2< 0$. So it's sufficient to assume $x-1< 0$ and you're done.

Comment: It is worthwhile trying to sketch the graph for such problems.

Answer (score 2):

The function is convex and $f({11 \over 2}+x) = f({11 \over 2}-x)$.
 Hence a $\min$ occurs at $x={11 \over 2}$, or $f({11\over 2}) = 25$.

(In fact, the $\min$ occurs for $x \in [5,6]$.)

Comment: that is a very clever solution!

Comment: @AlvinLepik: Thanks! Its not particularly original, a similar sort of problem occurs in $l^1$ minimisation, one can show that the median is a minimiser of the $l^1$ norm

Comment: Dear copper, I don't understand this. May be I haven't a knowledge on convex function. Could you explain it further....otherwise please tell me the areas I should cover to understand this

Comment: @Buddhike: Hi, don't worry about it, convex analysis is a delightful topic, but not necessary to answer this question. It does, however, give a very simple answer. I just wanted to give an alternative approach. It might help to plot the function for just $|x-1|+|x-2|$ to get an idea of what it looks like.

Comment: @copper.hat: Thank you so much for clarification

Comment: How do you know $f$ is convex? @copper.hat

Comment: @Angle: The function $x \mapsto |x-k|$ is convex, this follows from the definition, and the sum of convex functions is convex, which also follows form the definition. Also, norms are always convex, and the function can be expressed in terms of the 1-norm.

Answer (score 1):

Just use triangle inequality:

$$|x-1|+|x-2|+\dots+|x-10| = |1-x|+|2-x|+\dots+|5-x|+ |x-6|+|x-7|\dots+|x-10| >$$ $$|1-x+2-x+...+x-10| = |15-6-7-8-9-10| = |-25|$$

Comment: Yes ..it seems correct. But how do I come to that decision my self initially?

Comment: Well since you have even number of $x$ and you know $|-a|=|a|$ one might think how could we eliminate $x$ to get some estimate.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: by the triangle inequality $|x-1|+|x-10| = |x-1|+|10-x| \ge |x-1+10-x|=9$. The same way, $\,|x-2|+|x-9|\ge 7\,$, $\,|x-3|+|x-8|\ge 5\;\ldots$

Comment: Then is 25 the minimum value that the inequality can get?

Comment: @Buddhike That's correct. The above shows that the sum is always $\,\ge 9+7+5+3+1=25\,$, and that's an actual minimum since it is attained for $\,x \in [5,6]\,$.

Comment: Thank you so much for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

The LHS is a piecewise linear function, so it can only achieve a minimum at a "turning" point, when one of the arguments is zero.

We have

$$|1-1|+|2-1|+\cdots|1-10|=0+1+\cdots 9=45,$$

$$|2-1|+|2-2|+\cdots|2-10|=1+0+1+\cdots 8=37,$$

$$\cdots$$

and the minimum is achieved with

$$|5-1|+|5-2|+\cdots|5-10|=4+3+2+1+0+1+\cdots 5=25.$$

---

Algebraically, we have

$$S_k=\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}(k-i)+\sum_{i={k+1}}^{10}(i-k)=k^2-11k+55$$

and the minimum is found on either sides of the continuous minimum.